# Android Realm: Out of memory

Tags: android, realm

Use cycle in which more than 3000 iterations:

```
for (Element e2 : elinks2) {
    AllAuthors allauthor = new AllAuthors();
    allauthor.setUrl_base(href.substring(0, href.length() - 1));
    allauthor.setAuthor_fio(e2.text().trim());
    allauthor.setLetters(e.attr("href"));

    Realm realm_2 = null;
    try {
           realm_2 = Realm.getInstance(new File(func.getFolder("db")), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
           realm_2.beginTransaction();
           realm_2.copyToRealmOrUpdate(allauthor);
           realm_2.commitTransaction();
    } finally {
           if(realm_2 != null) {
               realm_2.close();
           }
    }
}
```

After you add (or update) about 1000 records an error

```
Out of memory in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 164
```

swears on line

```
realm_2.commitTransaction();
```

What advise?

AllAuthors.class:

```
@RealmClass
public class AllAuthors extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String url_base;

    private String author_fio;

    private String letters;

    ....Standard getters & setters generated....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are continuously opening and closing a Realm while at the same time having a lot of small transactions. While that pattern is very inefficient, it shouldn't by itself cause you to run out of memory. However if you are running this in a background thread, for each transaction Realm will have to maintain a diff to the original data until Realms on all threads can be brought up to date (which happens on a Looper events or calling Realm.refresh()). I would suggest refactoring to the below, which is both faster and less memory intensive:

```
Realm realm_2 = Realm.getInstance(new File(func.getFolder("db")), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name_db) + ".realm");
realm_2.beginTransaction();
for (Element e2 : elinks2) {
    AllAuthors allauthor = new AllAuthors();
    allauthor.setUrl_base(href.substring(0, href.length() - 1));
    allauthor.setAuthor_fio(e2.text().trim());
    allauthor.setLetters(e.attr("href"));
    realm_2.copyToRealmOrUpdate(allauthor);
}
realm_2.commitTransaction();
realm_2.close();
```